# Do all websites in a shared hosting have the same IP address?

Tags: shared-hosting

If a shared webhost server like hostgator (for example) host 100 sites, will all the 100 sites have the same IP address?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily, you can have multiple IP addresses on a server, and accounts can share IP addresses or be assigned dedicated IP addresses. If a domain uses an SSL certificate for example, that would require a dedicated IP address to be assigned.

The default setup for most servers is to share IP addresses however since they're limited, so more than likely shared hosting accounts on the same server will have the same IP address.

Comment: The reason i asked is that Google SERP ranking "seems" to check for backlinks using IPs too. Big webhost like hostgator, JustHost etc "may" have 1000s of website having same IP. So, it'll give a false negative impression on Google's eye

Comment: That's really a separate question, which comes up on this site occasionally. The consensus seems to be, that for the same reason (i.e., lots of sites might have the same IP), then Google would be unfairly penalizing them if it did. Its algorithm _may_ however take into consideration if lots of inbound/outbound links are coming from the same IP.

Comment: yes, exactly. That's what i'm worried about. Google should not penalize it. But If Google don't penalize them then Blackhat SEO can take a BIG advantage of unlimited addon features (which we get by just $10)

Comment: See the last bit I just added to my comment :-)

Comment: hehe ya, Google Algo is smart enough.... hmmm...